# How to use fopen() in 2 different functions

Tags: c

The main function is required code given by my professor. However, I want to write to the file in "compare()", but it only writes the last time the function is run. How would I be able to write to the file without resetting it every time "compare()" is called?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void compare(void);

int main(void) {
    int i;
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("largeSmallLab.txt", "r+");
    
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
        compare();
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

void compare() {
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("largeSmallLab.txt", "r+");
    
    int num1, num2, num3, num4;
    
    printf("Insert 4 numbers: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    scanf("%d", &num3);
    scanf("%d", &num4);
    
    if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3 && num1 > num4) {
        printf("Largest: %d \n", num1);
        fprintf(fp, "Largest: %d \n", num1);
    } else if (num2 > num1 && num2 > num3 && num2 > num4) {
        printf("Largest: %d \n", num2);
        fprintf(fp, "Largest: %d \n", num2);
    } else if (num3 > num1 && num3 > num2 && num3 > num4) {
        printf("Largest: %d \n", num3);
        fprintf(fp, "Largest: %d \n", num3);
    } else if (num4 > num1 && num4 > num2 && num4 > num3) {
        printf("Largest: %d \n", num4);
        fprintf(fp, "Largest: %d \n", num4);
    }
    
    if (num1 < num2 && num1 < num3 && num1 < num4) {
        printf("Smallest: %d \n", num1);
        fprintf(fp, "Smallest: %d \n", num1);
    } else if (num2 < num1 && num2 < num3 && num2 < num4) {
        printf("Smallest: %d \n", num2);
        fprintf(fp, "Smallest: %d \n", num2);
    } else if (num3 < num1 && num3 < num2 && num3 < num4) {
        printf("Smallest: %d \n", num3);
        fprintf(fp, "Smallest: %d \n", num3);
    } else if (num4 < num1 && num4 < num2 && num4 < num3) {
        printf("Largest: %d \n", num4);
        fprintf(fp, "Smallest: %d \n", num4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Open the file in `a` mode to append to the file. `r+` mode is writing at the beginning of the file, not the end.

Comment: The professorial code is singularly pointless — the file is opened for reading and writing, but nothing in the main function modifies the file, and nothing outside the main function can access the file stream. So, the calls to `fopen()` and `fclose()` are pretty pointless. The code should check that the result of `fopen()` is not NULL and should avoid calling `fclose()` if the result is NULL. I think you run into problems if you enter the four values `1 1 2 2` (for example) — none of the conditions evaluates to true, so you never print anything. Opening the file in append mode makes sense too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try passing the file handle as a parameter to you compare routine. Thus opening the file once in the external code, and then 'using it' within your compare, lastly closing it at the outer loop.

void compare(FILE *fP) ;

Alternatively if you wanted your compare routine to do the work, ensuring the outer loop does not need to know about the logging function of 'compare' you could use "a" for append mode when calling fopen.

Comment: The 'required code' constraint probably means that the OP cannot change the code in `main()` and hence can't change the call to `compare()` to pass information.  I agree that means there's no real point to the code in `main()` that handles the file  It's a weird setup.